# How to upload data to Amazon Redshift

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I want to upload data to a Redshift automatically.

I know how to access redshift and extract data. but I don't know how to load data into a table.

I heard that you need a commit feature. I want to know how to commit or the name of the module (like pycopg2).

Answer (score 1):

The recommended method for loading data into Amazon Redshift is to place the data in an Amazon S3 bucket, then use the [COPY](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY.html) command to load the data from S3. This method is very efficient and utilizes the parallel processing capabilities of the entire cluster.

It is recommended *NOT* to use an INSERT command for large quantities of data (but it is okay for a few lines).

Therefore, you automation steps are:

- Store the data in an S3 bucket
- Issue a COPY command to the Redshift cluster (via SQL, so you could use psycopg2)